# Html: css disable user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I want to disable user agent stylesheet in my code. I lookes for it but the only answeres were:

1. Disable direct in the browser (makes no sense, because when i launche the website on a other website it's active again)
2. Just override it (I could do that, but then I have to override 11 Attributs (would take to much pc power over large things))

Comment: Could you inspect the element and locate it?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to disable user agent stylesheet in my code.

This is impossible.

> Just override it

This is your only option.